# Queue not working in discord.js, skips the old song

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js to play music but the queue is not working even though the code looks right to me and there are no errors in the console. whenever I type $play (any new song link) it just skips the old song and starts playing the new song instead of saving it in the queue and play one by one

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const client = new discord.Client(); 
const prefix = '$';

var servers = {};

switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }
                    else{
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });
            }
            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send('You need to provide a link!');
                return;
            }
            if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                message.channel.send('You must be in a channel to play music!');
                return;
            }
            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })
        break;

        case 'skip':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
            message.channel.send('Skipping the song')
        break;

        case 'stop':
            message.member.voice.channel.leave();
        break;

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error where you're checking if the bot is already in the voice channel, the `if` clause is wrong. As of Discord.js v12, a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) no longer has a property `.voiceConnection`. Instead, now you need to use [`Guild.voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=voice) to get the VoiceState and then call the [`.connection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=connection) property on that to check if your bot has a voice connection already established.

So the fix is changing this piece of code:

```js
if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)
```

To this:

```js
if(!message.guild.voice || !message.guild.voice.connection)
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined` this is an error I come upon after using your method!

Comment: @KanwarnoorSingh I've edited my answer. It was an oversight on my part, if the bot is not in a voice channel of the guild, `guild.voice` will be undefined. So I've added the extra check to see if `message.guild.voice` is not undefined and if `message.guild.voice.connection` is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

1. you are using .voiceConnection (not a property now)
2. if there is no voice connection then play member provided song (not checking if there is song in queue or not)

Code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const client = new discord.Client(); 
const prefix = '$';
const servers = {};

switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':
            function play(connection, message){
                let server = servers[message.guild.id];
                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
                server.queue.shift();
                server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]) return play(connection, message);
                    connection.disconnect();
                });
            };
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You need to provide a link!');
            if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You must be in a channel to play music!');
            if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            };

            const server = servers[message.guild.id];

            if (server.queue.length >= 1) {
              server.queue.push(args[1]);
              return message.channel.send("added to queue!");
            };

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            });
        break;
        case 'skip':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
            message.channel.send('Skipping the song')
        break;
        case 'stop':
            message.member.voice.channel.leave();
        break;
    }
})
```

Links:
[Discord.js Official Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/)